# Open a Url using AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask

I am a tyro in Android application and I have hit a stonewall where I want to open a browser on clicking a button. Right now what I am doing is opening the background over my app, is there any method by which you can open the browser in the background?

I just need to hit that URL on the browser. I have tried AsyncTask too and I am adding my snippet here. The code is without any error but when I am running the app on my mobile the app is crashing. I think there is some mistake I am making inside AsyncTask.

```
public void led2off(View view)
{
    finalResult.setText("led2 turned off");
    try
    {
        URL myURL = new URL("http://172.17.27.173/?5");
        new UrlPinger().execute(myURL);
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class UrlPinger extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try {
            URLConnection myURLConnection = urls[0].openConnection();
            myURLConnection.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the image is intended to show your code, rather than something in your IDE, would you replace it with text please? A formatting tool is available.

Comment: I have written the piece of code in the format, i hope that better helps you people in understanding what i mean to say.